# OpenSSL EVP_CIPHER_CTX get updated IV

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

I'm using OpenSSL EVP_Encrypt APIs, with AES_ctr_128 mode. I'm trying to retrieve the updated (incremented counter)
In OpenSSL 1.1.0 we **CANNOT** simply do:

```
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    /*
    EVP_EncryptInit(ctx, ...);
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ...);
    EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, ...);
    */
    memcpy(iv, ctx->iv, sizeof(ctx->iv);
```

since the ctx structure is hidden (getting incomplete type error with the above code).

Also there is no any get API for this field.

Is there any way to get the updated IV buffer stored in EVP_CIPHER_ctx structure (Incremented IV)?

Answer (score 1):

The IV alone is only enough if you write a fixed number of blocks (with block size 16 for AES) to the cipher. So you need to keep track of the amount of data written anyway.

To retrieve the counter value it is therefore easier if you simply calculate it yourself. Then you can restart the cipher stream for a specific IV. Note that you may still have to skip an amount of plain or ciphertext, for instance by encrypting zero valued bytes, before you can continue the operation.

So to calculate the counter value simply perform addition of the IV with the number of complete blocks processed: `len(pt) / n` where `len` is the length in bytes and `n = 16` using integer division. The IV consists of the nonce and the initial counter value as a fixed size big endian number. So you can just add each byte of the IV with each byte of the integer, taking the possible carry from right to left (high index for the least significant byte, to low index with the most significant byte).

To calculate how many bytes you need to skip (i.e. encrypt/decrypt before the key stream is again synchronized you simply calculate `len(pt) % n` where `%` is the remainder or modulus operator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I wanted to know if OpenSSL itself provides any API/way to get the IV from ctx (the IV that was updated by OpenSSL). Only if this doesn't exist, I'll implement the increment operation myself